# Batch Rename a file based of part of name of second file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cat, batch-rename

I want to batch rename some file based of Part of Name of other files
let me explain my question with a example, I think its better in this way
I have **some file** with these name in a **folder**

```
sc_gen_08-bigfile4-0-data.txt
signal_1_1-bigfile8.1-0-data.txt
```

and these file in **other folder**

```
sc_gen_08-acaaf2d4180b743b7b642e8c875a9765-1-data.txt
signal_1_1-dacaaf280b743b7b642e8c875a9765-4-data.txt
```

I want to batch rename **first** files to name of **second** files, how can I do this? also file in both first and second folder have common in name

`name(common in file in both folder)-[only this part is diffrent in each file]-data.txt`

Thanks (sorry if its not a good question for everyone, but its a question for me)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Can you please clear this for me? You have one folder with a few files and then you have other folder with other files. You want to name the files from the first folder with the name of the files of the second folder, right? Other question...all the files in both folders have in common the name? For example, is there only one sc_gen_08*? Other question...Folder A and B have exactly the same number of files?

Comment: @vsergi thanks for reply, yes its exactly what I want to do, and yes all files have common in name (`name(common in file in both folder)-(only this part is diffrent in each file)-data.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's name the original folder as "folder1" and the other folder as "folder2". Then would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1="folder1"                       # the original folder name
folder2="folder2"                       # the other folder name

declare -A map                          # create an associative array
for f in "$folder2"/*-data.txt; do      # find files in the "other folder"
    f=${f##*/}                          # remove directory name
    common=${f%%-*}                     # extract the common substring
    map[$common]=$f                     # associate common name with full filename
done

for f in "$folder1"/*-data.txt; do      # find files in the original folder
    f=${f##*/}                          # remove directory name
    common=${f%%-*}                     # extract the common substring
    mv -- "$folder1/$f" "$folder1/${map[$common]}"
                                        # rename the file based on the value in map
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If your files are all called as you mentioned. I have created the next script.

It is located following the next structure.

```
root@vm:~/test# ll
folder1/
folder2/
script.sh
```

The script is the next:

```
#Declare folders
folder1=./folder1
folder2=./folder2

#Create new folder if it does not exist
if [ ! -d ./new ]; then
  mkdir ./new;
fi

#Iterate over first directory
for file1 in folder1/*; do
        #Iterate over second directory
        for file2 in folder2/*; do
                #Compare begining of each file, if they match, they will be copied.
                if [[ $(basename $file1 | cut -f1 -d-) == $(basename $file2 | cut -f1 -d-) ]]; then
                    echo $(basename $file1) $(basename $file2) "Match"
                    cp folder1/$(basename $file1) new/$(basename $file2)
                fi
        done
done
```

It creates a folder called new and will copy all your files there. If you want to delete them, use mv instead. But I didn't want to use mv in the first attempt just in case to get some undesired effect.